# How To Implement The EVP_aes_256_cbc Using the OpenSSL Library in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement EVP_aes_256_cbc in the OpenSSL library following this link: [EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption)

As it can bee seen in the above link, the "key" and the "plaintext" have been hardcoded as follows:

```
unsigned char *key = (unsigned char *)"01234567890123456789012345678901"; 
unsigned char *plaintext = (unsigned char *)"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
```

this works fine, but In my application, "key" and the "plaintext" should not be hardcoded, instead, I have to read each of them from the buffer of a signal of type byte (I am using a simulator(its a collection of codes) that reads data from a file and saves it into a signal).

What I did is the following:

1. I read the 16 bytes of the plaintext from the buffer (using the
   "bufferGet" function) and I stored the data in a byte array of size
   16.
2. I read the 32 bytes of the key from the buffer (using the
   "bufferGet" function) and again I stored the data in a byte array of size 32.
3. Since the inputs of the "encrypt function" are pointers, I should
   creat pointers to the arrays (i am not sure if I am doing it
   correctly)
4. Then I call the encrypt function and it provides me the ciphertext.
5. I save the ciphertext into a signal of type byte.

However, I am not having a correct output. I think the problem is with the 3rd step because in the debugger I see some extra garbage at the end of the pointers. please check the following picture:

[Debagger Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYGBD.jpg)

I have to mention that I am new in programming and what I did may not be correct. I highly appreciate your help in solving the problem.

Here are my codes: (t_raw is equal to byte)

```
// # Reading plaintext and key from the signals
t_raw alicePlainIn[16]{};
inputSignals[0]->bufferGet((std::byte*)alicePlainIn, 16);
t_raw aliceKeys[32]{};
inputSignals[1]->bufferGet((std::byte*)aliceKeys, 32);

// # Encryption Process
ciphertext_len = encrypt((unsigned char*)plaintext, strlen((char*)plaintext), key, iv, 
ciphertext);

// # Saving the Ciphertext into a Signal 
for (auto cipher_text : ciphertext)
{
outputSignals[0]->bufferPut((t_raw)cipher_text);
}
```

Comment: Does the example code compile? You are passing a variable named `plaintext` but earlier, you populate `alicePlainIn`? Anyway, I suggest you pass the actual length of the buffer as opposed to using `strlen`, which will search the input argument for a `NULL` terminating character which probably doesn't exist in your case. <<Edit>>: Ah, I see from the debugger screenshot that you are assigning `plaintext` to `alicePlainIn`; the comment still stands though, `strlen` will break.

Comment: @wobr: Yes, it is compiling. but the output is too long and incorrect. Although the plaintext and alicePlainIn refers to the same data, their types are different. the plaintext is a pointer, that's why I used a different name. I applied your changes, although the output length get shorter, it is not correct yet. do I need to make changes for the "key" as well? Thank you.

Comment: Ah sorry yes you would do, but there may be other issues if the output length is wrong after your first fix. Fix the key and let me know how it's looking :)

Comment: Also, please update the question to cover full source code to assist future visitors.

Comment: @wobr: Unfortunately the simulator is huge and it is not possible to include all the codes, however, what you said about the strlen was correct and it solved the problem. Thank you so much for your time and explanations.

Comment: Hey - great news. Happing encrypting!

Comment: I upvoted the question for pointing me to EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption. Thanks!